# Conditional Formatting color row if criteria true

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have figured out this formula to get the values from the row if the input value is equal or greater to the value in the first column of the table.

Input cell: B4

Formula in cell C4 to retrieve the corresponding value in the table e.g.: `=IF(ISBLANK($B$4),"",INDEX(C14:C31,MATCH(TRUE,B14:B31>=$B$4,0)))`

What I need is a conditional formatting that the specific row will be colored after the input in cell B4 with the help of the formula, but I can't figure out how.

Any suggestions appreciated.

edit: if possible I would like to use the listobject/table name instead of the row range.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your format condition you have to check the result of your formula against the current row

Use this formula for the format condition (assuming that you highlighted B14: F31 - and that you have a German Excel - as you have to use the German version within format condition)

`=UND($B$4<>"";(ZEILE($B14)-13) = VERGLEICH(WAHR;$B$14:$B$31>=$B$4;0))`

or in english:
`=AND($B$4<>"",(ROW($B14)-13) = MATCH(TRUE,$B$14:$B$31>=$B$4,0))`